# $2^x$ exponential congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, exponentiation, congruences

How does one go about solving this congruence:
$$2^x+8\equiv0\pmod{27}$$
I wrote a program to go over many values of x, and it seems that $x=12+18t$ where $t\in \Bbb N$. How would I get to that conclusion without going through every x?
There was a similar question here: [Solution to exponential congruence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1755525/solution-to-exponential-congruence), but unless I misunderstood, these solutions only work if 27 was a prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tip:
Find a generator of the group, write the equation as

$a^x=a^t \space mod \space k$

And solve
$x=t\space mod\space  \phi(k) \space\space\space$ $\phi$ representing Euler totient function

Answer (score 1):

Use [Euler's totient theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem) with $\varphi(27) = 18$.